# Pushing the result of a join into a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

New to SQL, been messing around with it a bit. I'm using Microsoft SQL Management Studio 2008. I was wondering if there was a way to push the result of a SQL query into a new table? Anyway, thanks for any help ahead of time!

EDIT: Sorry about the lack of the query guys, my bad.

```
SELECT *
FROM UnaData AS Una
FULL OUTER JOIN GCData AS GC
ON 
    GC.[Bill Rate] = Una.[Bill Rate] AND
    GC.[Employee Name] = Una.username AND
    GC.Revenue = Una.[Bill Rate] * Una.[Hours] AND
    GC.[Contract Number] = Una.[Project Code] AND
    GC.[Job Category] = Una.[Cost Element] AND
    GC.[Hours Billed] = Una.[Hours] 
WHERE
    Una.username IS NULL OR
    GC.[Employee Name] IS NULL
ORDER BY
    Una.[Project Code]
```

Comment: `SELECT blablabla INTO dbo.newTable FROM YourQuery`

Comment: Id rather put it this way ... FROM (YourQuery). This could be the reason for the OP's syntax error (see below).

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! I got it all figured out as per the best answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple method is with a `into` statement.

```
select *
into #temptable
-- from sometable join someothertable on ...
-- where conditions
```

Edit: Per OP's query

```
select t.*
into #temptable
from 
(SELECT *
FROM UnaData AS Una
FULL OUTER JOIN GCData AS GC
ON GC.[Bill Rate] = Una.[Bill Rate] AND
GC.[Employee Name] = Una.username AND
GC.Revenue = Una.[Bill Rate] * Una.[Hours] AND
GC.[Contract Number] = Una.[Project Code] AND
GC.[Job Category] = Una.[Cost Element] AND
GC.[Hours Billed] = Una.[Hours] 
WHERE Una.username IS NULL OR GC.[Employee Name] IS NULL
) t
```

You entire query will now be treated as a table `t` and you can insert `into` your `#temptable`. Also, you shouldn't use `order by` when you are selecting `into` a table. It has been removed.

Comment: Huh. It's telling me invalid syntax so I must be doing something wrong. It doesn't seem to like it when I do that. Let me take another look.

Comment: if you could post the query you had before, it would help

Comment: Sorry man. Just did so in the original post. Thanks for the help so far. :)

Comment: modified it @DavidBittner..check it and let me know..one thing here..it is better to select only the columns you need instead of saying `*` in the `select` clause.

Answer (score -7):

You can use the following SQL query:

```
//following line creates a new table with the same schema as 'table_name'

create table new_table_name as select * from table_name

insert into new_table_name select * from table_name;
```

Comment: this doesn't create a new table, just inserts data on an existing one

Comment: @lamak He did not ask for table creation

Comment: "way to push the result of a SQL query into a **new table**", I don't know how inserting data into an existing table answers this

Comment: Yes, and the syntax for creating a table that you are using is wrong for SQL Server

Comment: @Lamak It is not necessary that he wants to create a table

Comment: And queries are usually not as simple as `select * from table;`. They often have less columns or extra columns or joins and columns from multiple tables.

Comment: @AmitRaj I seriously don't understand how the need to put the results of a query into a new table makes it not necessary to create a table somehow

Comment: @ypercube requester did not mention any query.

Comment: *"I was wondering if there was a way to push the result of a SQL **query** into a **new table**?"*

Comment: I used the above queries then gave the answer

Comment: You did. Problem is, though, that `create table ... as select ...` doesn't work in SQL Server.